# I want to build a custom router for Zend framework supports lang & country

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

Here is an example of what i want to do
The Url will be as follow

```
http://www.example.com/en/us/directory/companies/view/4433225.html
Where is
en: is the lang
us: is the country
directory: is the module
companies: is the controller
view: is the action
4433225.html: is sort of parameter send to the action could be the company name like this company-name.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using a [Conventional Modular Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html). Then you could specify different controller directories per language and so on...

Comment: Yes I do using Conventional Modular Directory Structure
What I want to do is exclude the first 2 segments from the routing system 

as ar/us is not controllers or action the just parameters to define the site lang and country

Comment: Did you take a look to rewrite rules, for example: `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`, I think with it you could configure which part of your URLs means language, controller, action and so on...

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex